# Documentation for Tor, Orbot, Orfox, etc

Tags: support

Where can I get an education in using Tor, both on my phone, and on a computer?  I'm looking to securely set my items up, as there are many options that I know nothing about.  Is there a site for reading documentation on these?  I don't know what the settings do in Orbot for example, and would like to be able to look at an explanatory list, if there is one, or be directed to a course that teaches these things.  Thankyou in advance, as I expect there is information available, considering the scope of the project, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I have mine in russian with basic tor configuration how-to's. Will it be of use?